# Wifi signal drops out at random (apparently) moments

Tags: wireless

Set up: Bt Home Hub Router, two laptops Ubuntu 11:10 and other 11:04 and iPod Touch.

I live in a small rural village in the UK and have had no problems with wifi for many months. In the past 3 days our wifi drops out in that we can "see" the SSID from the Router but neither of the laptops nor the iTouch can access the internet. On all 3 days the drop out has occurred when my neighbour's father parks his Toyota Prius (hybrid with many batteries) across the road. We can access the internet when connected via ethernet cable.
To check the theory our wifi dropped out when he arrived and worked again THE MINUTE he left! 
I've spoken to the neighbours and they (in their own words) are a non-tech family in that they have an iPad and BT Router only and no other technical gadget they use.
Yesterday I checked to see if the problem was caused by the Prius being charged but it was not. 
As I say because we are in a small community it is relatively easy to ascertain if anything untoward is going on and the only "change" that coincides with the wifi drop out is this car arriving.
Has anyone heard of this issue? I have "googled" this but to no avail.
Any ideas and help will be gratefully received.

Comment: I don't think this question belongs on an Ubuntu Q&A site, as it is clearly an issue with your router and not with Ubuntu. But it is interesting! Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

interesting issue!

I would take a closer look at your wireless signal strength.  If it is particular week, any "metallic" object could have interference.

More likely is clashing wireless channels - for the UK, most routers default to wireless channel 1.  Try changing to either 6 or 11.

Comment: Thanks, according to the router it has an automatic channel selector supposedly going to the strongest signal. After I was able to get back onto the router yesterday the channel was number 6 (of 11) and when "refreshed" it is supposed to choose 1, 6 or 11. I refreshed and it went to 11. I'll keep a look out for the next few days.